# remove all mp4 files recursively from selected directories

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
UltrastarDaily% tree -L 1
.
├── lost+found
├── purple_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-38-44am
├── purple_rsync_bak.06-02-21_07-41-32pm
├── purple_rsync_bak.07-02-21_08-02-51am
├── purple_rsync_bak.07-02-21_08-17-26am
├── purple_rsync_bak.08-02-21_02-00-06am
├── red_rsync_bak.01-02-21_06-11-39pm
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-16-58am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-23-24am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-26-58am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-27-30am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-31-36am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-33-14am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-34-04am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-34-52am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-35-22am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_06-41-48am
├── red_rsync_bak.06-02-21_07-39-41pm
├── red_rsync_bak.07-02-21_08-01-14am
├── red_rsync_bak.07-02-21_08-17-41am
├── red_rsync_bak.07-02-21_08-38-52am
├── red_rsync_bak.08-02-21_01-56-43am
├── red_rsync_bak.27-01-21_06-13-39pm
├── red_rsync_bak.28-01-21_02-22-31pm
├── red_rsync_bak.30-01-21_12-48-03am
├── rsync-WDPurple.log
├── rsync-WDRed.log
├── WDPurple
└── WDRed
```

I want to delete all `.mp4` files recursively from `...._rsync_bak....` directories.

Currently I am using the command:

```
find ./ -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*_rsync_bak.*.mp4" -delete
```

However, it does not make sure I am only searching the root directory. It might also delete `mp4`s from directories that are named like `...._rsync_bak....` but inside `WDPurple` or `WDRed` directory.

Comment: Just use `-maxdepth 2` to delete the files inside the directories you mentioned, but ignoring the subdirectories within them. Also don't forget to add `-type f` to only select files. https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the directories in the search path

```
find ./*_rsync_bak.* -type f -name '*.mp4' -print    # -delete
```

Replace `-print` with `-delete`, or simply append `-delete` to the end of the command, once you are sure it's picking up no more than the files you expect